# Is it reasonable to compare models by confidence interval width?

Tags: confidence-interval, model-comparison, wilcoxon-signed-rank

I am estimating values for the number of users holding a stock. Afterwards, I subtract the number of users that actually hold the stock in the time period from it. Let's call the result of the calculations X.
For the linear regression model I use to estimate this, I use different estimation windows (number of days) as input and estimate the number of users for different time length.
This leads to more than 250 different result arrays.
In theory, the mean of X should be around 0 if there is no extrinsic effect. t-tests show that X is statistically significantly different from 0 for basically all models. I attribute a part of this to the high variance in the underlying data and my estimation models not being able to account for this.

I still want to separate the better from the worse models.
There is a big difference between the confidence intervals for X among these.

A visual assessment and Wilcoxon pairwise comparisons resulted in two groups of models that performed better than others based on their confidence interval width.

Does it make sense and is it feasible in academic work to compare the width of the confidence intervals as a proxy to assess which models were giving more accurate estimations / performing better than others?

Here is an excerpt from my data to bring some life into the question:

| event_window | X | p_value | conf_width | estimation_window |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| t-0, t+1 | 0.0160 | 0 | 0.00553 | 40 Days |
| t-3, t+3 | 0.07176517 | 1.00e-17 | 0.033055918 | 110 Days |

Comment: perhaps you meant *width*, not *length*

Comment: I certainly did! Thanks for the info. I edited the question accordingly and added a short example

Comment: (1) What is your definition of "better performing"? Without knowing the truth you can't know which model gives more accurate estimators (unless you validate on new data). (2) Generally the theory behind confidence intervals assumes that the model is *not* chosen based on the data. In particular this means that if you choose the model that gives you the shortest intervals, these intervals will quite certainly be too short due to selection bias.

Comment: In many circumstances, the model with the *wider* confidence interval is the better one because it more accurately assesses the uncertainty.  (It is worth contemplating the effects of overfitting in this context.)  Thus, using CI widths by themselves as proxies for model accuracy is at best a dubious procedure.  To assess *accuracy* you need to compare your model's fit to *known* values that are not used in developing the model itself.

Comment: Thank you for the insightful feedback @ChristianHennig and @whuber! I learned a lot and will take your comments into consideration for my future work, merci